# Select where a column equals any value from another query

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query to find relationships in a table named entryEntryPairs:

```
if (!$result = $mysqli->query(
    "SELECT entryIdA AS relatedId FROM entryEntryPairs WHERE entryIdB = ".$inRow["id"].
    " UNION ".
    "SELECT entryIdB AS relatedId FROM entryEntryPairs WHERE entryIdA = ".$inRow["id"]
)) return "Something went wrong";
```

However, what I really want is to use all of the `relatedId`s as part of a larger query to a table named entry. Something of the form:

`SELECT title FROM entry WHERE id =`

The missing section to the right of `id =` would be all of the `relatedIds`. Can this be done in a single larger query or do I have to iterate over the results of the first query plugging in each `relatedId` to the right of `id =`?

Comment: Maybe posting your schema would help a lot

Comment: I don't see what more is needed... table entryEntryPairs has two columns: entryIdA and entryIdB. All that matters here for table entry is that it has at least columns: title and id (entryIdA and entryIdB are always acceptable values for id)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try with `IN` like

```
"SELECT title FROM entry WHERE id IN (SELECT entryIdA AS relatedId FROM entryEntryPairs WHERE entryIdB = ".$inRow["id"].
" UNION ".
"SELECT entryIdB AS relatedId FROM entryEntryPairs WHERE entryIdA = ".$inRow["id"].")"
```